# The Star Wars scripts on IMSDB contain many lines and scenes that aren't in the movies. Were the scripts on this site actually written by Lucas?

Tags: star-wars, george-lucas

I've read the scripts for the prequel movies on IMSDB. They're definitely not a transcription of the movie as the contain many lines and even scenes not in the movies. For example, in the Attack of the Clones script, there's a scene where Padmé put the plating on C3PO while Anakin searched for his mother on Tatooine. Did Lucas write this or is this scene and the other changes fan fiction put there by someone who wanted to add their own touch to the script? Is there any evidence these scripts were written by Lucas?

Comment: The AotC script on IMSDB appears to be the 2nd draft script from 2000. There's a later version of the script that was on [BlueHarvest](https://web.archive.org/web/20120112042743/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/aotc-script.shtml) that's closer to the actual film.

Comment: Oh cool. How do you know that? Do you know if it was a genuine draft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several versions of the Attack of the Clones script available on the internet. The one on IMSDB seems to be an OCR'd copy of a [scanned PDF](http://docdro.id/0klcx1G) dated July 2000 and which includes "Blue Revisions" from March 2000. The formatting, writing style and length are consistent with other Lucasfilm Star Wars scripts that have been released.

The site BlueHarvest.net (formerly one of the most respected Star Wars fan sites on the internet) acquired a [copy of the next dated version](https://web.archive.org/web/20120112042743/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/aotc-script.shtml) , marked as

> Third Draft, Last Revision - September 5, 2001

By this point, the screenplay no longer contains the scene with Padmé providing C-3PO's coverings but the rest of the script lines up nicely with the other version.

**TL;DR. I could do this for all of the Star Wars scripts on IMDB, but suffice to say that they all appear to be 100% genuine, albeit not necessarily the most up-to-date versions.**

Comment: This is a longshot but do you know anywhere I can view all versions of all of the Star Wars scripts? I'd love to see how the scripts evolved.

Comment: @PhloxMidas - This is probably a good start. https://www.reddit.com/r/Screenwriting/comments/3pems4/screenplay_links_imdb_top_250_movies/ You might also want to look at https://web.archive.org/web/20120102002727/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/ to find some alternate versions.

Comment: I'm no expert, but would I be right in thinking that all deleted scenes and even some others must appear in a script? Deleted scenes are obviously all acted so must be in a script, and surely there are others they decide to omit in the process of filming?

Comment: @ThruGog -  Yes, but some are added very late in the day or added in "pickup" when the director realises that he's massively cocked up the continuity or created a plot-hole.

Comment: @Richard - Are they likely to appear in the full script at all?

Comment: @ThruGog - pickup scenes aren't. Sometimes you find them in shooting scripts and "dailies".

Comment: You can see some pickup footage being added to the Hobbit films in the videos here; http://www.firstshowing.net/2013/watch-the-hobbit-production-video-blog-chronicles-pick-up-scenes/